# Resource is not local - creating files in Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

So, I'm trying to set up my Eclipse plugin so that it can process some data and generate some files within a project. I can create an `IFolder` using `project.getFolder().create` and create the right `IFile` objects with `project.getFile().create()`. Once created, however, they show up in the project navigator, but I get a lot of error about the resources being "not local," and they don't seem to show up in my filesystem. What's happening, and what do I need to change?

Here's the code to create the folder:

```
IFolder f = project.getFolder(folderName);
if (!f.exists()) f.create(false, false, null);
```

And my code for creating an `IFile` is essentially the same. The plugin is just running on my local file system, so I assume it's something in my code creating the error.

Comment: Could you update your question with a proper code snippet that shows the create?  Is your project hosted on a remote EFS?  Or just a standard local directory?

Comment: Just a standard local directory, and I added the create code for a folder - I assume I'm missing some step or object needed to make it work, I'm just not sure where.

Comment: When you create the file, what kind of input stream do you give it?

Comment: I've been using a ByteArrayInputStream based on something I read while looking for answers before. I got it to work once, but when I tried deleting the file and trying again, the same error occurred.

Comment: How did you delete the file?  From within eclipse?

Comment: The single time it worked, the file showed up in my local file system so I deleted it there. In times when the file wasn't correctly created, I deleted it from within Eclipse.

Comment: If you remove something from the filesystem, the workspace can get out of sync.  Try refreshing your workspace (so it syncs back up with the file system).

Answer (score 2):

Check your input stream. If it's null or throws an IOException, f.create will still succeed. However the file will appear as not local in the Eclipse UI.

Comment: Does not apply to IFolders, but searching for "Resource not local" brought me to this question and this is the answer I was looking for, because in my case, I was dealing with IFile ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
IFolder f = project.getFolder(folderName);
if (!f.exists()) f.create(false, false, null);
```

In the second parameter in the `f.create(...)` method if set to true will make the folder LOCAL and errors will not come (at least it stopped in my case). Also, I saw these errors coming from team providers (like git etc).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I still don't understand it, but I do have something working. I didn't have a problem with folders, only with files. At first I was trying to set the file contents when creating the file:

```
file.create(contents, true, monitor);
```

This didn't work and I got the "Resource is not local" problem.

By splitting up the setting of the content into a separate step, suddenly things started to work:

```
file.create(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]), true, monitor);
file.setContents(content, false, false, monitor);
```

I hope that helps someone.